# .ipa , where i can found it

Tags: iphone

I have a great problem. How i can generate the .ipa of my iPhone application, and i can found it ? in iTunes ?  i have all provisionnig profile, just the .ipa is my problem

i have done build for archiving but i am seraching all and i don't found the .ipa to send it via email .
please, Help.

Thanks for yourn answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use "build for archiving", select "Archive" instead. You need to select a scheme targeted at a device (not the simulator) to do that. Then, in the organizer, click on the archived build and hit "Share" to generate your .ipa file.

Comment: How i do " you need to select a sheme targeted at device ( not the simulator)"

Comment: In the upper left corner of your XCode window there's a dropdown box where you may select the scheme to be used. If you connect a development device, it will shop up in that list. Select this device and usually you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the steps for make .ipa file.

1. build your project.
2. Go to build folder -> select target build folder -> select builded application file.
3. Make zip of that selected application file.
4. Rename that .zip file to .ipa then press enter -> click on **Use .ipa** option.
5. Put that .ipa file on **/Users/ **userName* */Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile/**
6. Open iTune -> click on App tab and then you can see your app there.
7. Now Sync it for use in device.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> Build->Products->urProduct.app->drag
>   into iTunes->select
>   app->right-Click->showInFinder->ipa

1. Build your project.
2. Go to Products in work tree
3. Select appname.app
4. Drag into iTunes
5. Right-click app and "Show in Finder"
6. Access .iPa